# How to rewrite Promise code to avoid warnings

Tags: javascript, promise, refactoring

I have the following code.

```
const cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
                      onSuccess: resolve,
                      onFailure: reject }); ).then((result : AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserSession) => {
                        const ret = result.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
                        return new LoginResult(ret, null);
                      }).catch((e: { message: string }) => {
                        return new LoginResult('', e.message);
                      });
```

This part

```
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
                      onSuccess: resolve,
                      onFailure: reject }); )
```

is highlighted with 'a Promise was found that appears to not have resolve...'

How can this be rewritten to get rid of the warning?

Comment: `onSuccess: (...args) => resolve(...args)`, maybe? What's giving the warning? Also: doesn't the AWS API support promises? I've used quite a few methods that do and `new Promise` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Not this one or I'm not using it right.

Comment: In your sample code, it looks like you're missing a closing brace for the new promise's executor function. I.e. `onFailure: reject }); )` should be `onFailure: reject }); })`. Try reformatting your code to see that clearer.

Comment: @dchang I added the bracket but the original error is still displayed

Comment: @GenaVerdel Gotcha, I overlooked your question about it being a warning. Anyways I think I have an answer for you below.

Comment: Who or what emits that warning? Are you using a linter? Which one?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is an [open tslint issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/tslint-microsoft-contrib/issues/329). For now you can try suppressing it with one of these comment flags.

```js
// tslint:disable:promise-must-complete
// tslint:disable-next-line:promise-must-complete
```